# Lua for ESP32: How to obtain time from an NTP server or from time.is or?

Tags: esp32

I'm working with Lua on the ESP32. I see that contrary to the Lua implementation for the ESP8266, there is no NTP module (correct me if I am wrong).

I have been looking at the **net** library, but am too stupid to put together something which would be able to get time info thus I would appreciate if somebody could offer an idea or a hint how to solve this problem.